# Django app with TextField version control system

Tags: django, version-control, editing

Is there any Django apps to handle TextField changes with the edit history?

Something like Stack Exchange question edit history works. With changes and diffs.

The best app I've found till now is [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion)

But it lacks the TextField diff feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion) is a reusable app for model's instance version management.

It has an extension [django-reversion-compare](https://github.com/jedie/django-reversion-compare) for versions comparison.

They are able to do exactly what I was looking for.

[image]